# prometheus alert expression for 99% availability of rest API

Tags: rest, prometheus, sli, sre

I would like to create an alert in Prometheus for a REST API, if the API is not available 99% of the time. I am new to prometheus expression. Could you please help me to create an expression to trigger this ALERT.
For example if i have a counter failed_counter that tracks the http failures. Please help.

Comment: How is possible to know if the REST is unavailable using a "counter"? I think a "gauge" is needed, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming that you are looking to implement a SLO strategy:
   Please, read this post

[implementing-slos-using-prometheus](https://engineering.bitnami.com/articles/implementing-slos-using-prometheus.html)

You can use the following tool for that: SLO generator.

[promtools SLOs](https://promtools.dev/alerts/errors)

This website could be helpful as well:

[awesome-prometheus-alerts](https://%20https://awesome-prometheus-alerts.grep.to/rules.html)

2. You can combine with black-box exporter

[blackbox_exporter](https://www.robustperception.io/tag/blackbox_exporter)